# Save relation with omniauth identity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I would like to let the user choose the service (free, standard, pro) in the registration step.

Here is the db model i'm working with:

(User)1---n(Subscription)n--1(Service)

In the "new user" form I have this customised code in order to let the user chose the service:

***identities/new.hmtl.erb***

```
<%= form_tag "/auth/identity/register", :html => {:role=>"form"} do %> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Service</label>
    <%= select("service", "service_id", @available_services, {:selected => params[:service_id]}, {class:"form-control"}) %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
      <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, class:"form-control" %>
    <p class="help-block">Nome e cognome completo e corretto.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Email</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :email, @identity.try(:email), class:"form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
      <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class:"form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Password confirmation</label>
      <%= password_field_tag :password_confirmation, nil, class:"form-control"%>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Sign up",class:"btn btn-default" %>
<% end %>
```

***identities_controller.rb***

```
class IdentitiesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :require_login
  layout "static"
  def new
    @available_services = Service.all.where(:id => [1, 2, 3]).collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
    @identity = env['omniauth.identity']
  end
end
```

Now, what's the way to create/save the user and the relation between the new user and the selected subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by...

Adding an hidden field for the service:

```
  #identitiy.new.html
  <%= hidden_field_tag :service_id, params[:service_id] %>
```

Edited the omniauth initializer as follow:

```
#omniauth.rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :identity,:fields => [:service_id,:name,:email], on_failed_registration: lambda { |env|
    IdentitiesController.action(:new).call(env)
}
end
```

Added attr_accessor and a after_create method in the Identity model:

```
#identity.rb
class Identity < OmniAuth::Identity::Models::ActiveRecord
  attr_accessor :service_id

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  #validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i

  after_create :add_subscription

  private
  def add_subscription
    Subscription.create(:user_id => self.id, :service_id => service_id.to_f)
  end

end
```